# Como transforma um projeto Spring Boot em um arquivo .jar?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Pessoal eu não sei como transformar um projeto Spring Boot em um arquivo .jar 
A minha tentativa foi entrar no projeto pelo **msdos** e com o comando **mvn install** poder criar o arquivo .jar 
Porém apareceram vários erros, não tem como colocar e mensagem de erro completa porque é muito grande, veja a mensagem abaixo;

[Mensagem de Erro](https://github.com/wladyband/erro1/blob/master/erro.txt)

Eu preferi colocar a mensagem de erro no GitHub porque é uma mensagem de erro muito grande.

Quando executo o projeto pelo **Spring Tool Suite** ele funciona normalmente.

aceito sugestões.

Eu também tentei executando esse comando:

```
Wladimir@wlady MINGW64 ~/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE
$ java -jar wladimir-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password algamoney.origin-permitida=http://localhost:4200
Error: Unable to access jarfile wladimir-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

O nome do meu projeto se chama **wladimir-api**

Answer (score 1):

Eu instalei o Java 8 e funcionou, encontrei a solução aqui:

[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

[Sofrência com Java 9: cadê meu JAXB?](https://alexandreaquiles.com.br/2017/10/13/sofrencia-com-java-9-cade-meu-jaxb/)